# I'm getting a 400 Bad Request on the Ebay API and I can't figure out why

Tags: java, post, apache-httpclient-4.x, ebay-api

I'm attempting to send the following (ebay API application token request) **POST** using Apache's **HttpClient**, and I keep on getting a **400: Bad Request** error, even though my code seems fine.

Here's the code:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;

import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class OrderFileDownload {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            OrderFileDownload od = new OrderFileDownload();
            System.out.println(od.submitTokenRequest());
    }

    public String submitTokenRequest()  throws Exception {
        String url = "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token";
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

        List<BasicNameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type","client_credentials"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri","<RuRedirect-value>"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scope","https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope"));

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.addHeader("Authorization","Basic " + encrypt64("<Client-Id>:<ClientSecret>"));

        HttpEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params);
        request.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response =  client.execute(request);
        client.close();

        return response.toString();
    }

    private String encrypt64(String text) {
        BASE64Encoder enc = new BASE64Encoder();
        return enc.encode(text.getBytes());
    }
}
```

This is the response the method returns:

```
HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Content-Type: text/plain, Content-Length: 0] [Content-Type: text/plain,Content-Length: 0,Chunked: false]}
```

Can anyone please help me figure this out?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while using the ebay API but if I add retry in my code which tries to attempt after a min then it works for me.

You can also try this but I have not found the root cause of it yet.

Thanks,

Parminder Singh